# osx dtruss doesn't report opening ~/.bash_profile while tracing bash?

Tags: bash, osx, dtrace

Let's assume I have this line at the start of my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
echo "*** THIS IS ~/.bash_profile RUNNING ***"
```

On a Linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04), I can inspect which files `bash` loads at startup with `strace`, so I do this:

```bash
strace -f bash --login 2>&1 | tee /tmp/log.strace
# type [ENTER] here, or "hello" [ENTER], then Ctrl+C to exit
grep 'bash_' /tmp/log.strace
```

The result is as expected:

> ```
> faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh", R_OK) = 0
> open("/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
> open("~/.bash_profile", O_RDONLY) = 3
> read(3, "echo \"*** THIS IS ~/.bash_profil"..., 48) = 48
> write(1, "*** THIS IS ~/.bash_profile RUNN"..., 40*** THIS IS ~/.bash_profile RUNNING ***
> ```

However, I've logged in on an OSX 10.9 machine via `ssh`, and I need to do the same. Since there is no `strace` on OSX, I used `dtruss`, like this:

```bash
dtruss -f bash --login 2>&1 | tee /tmp/log.dtruss
# type [ENTER] here, or "hello" [ENTER], then Ctrl+C to exit
grep 'bash_' /tmp/log.dtruss
```

Strangely, there seems to be no mention of `~/.bash_profile` ever being loaded:

> ```
> $ grep 'bash_' /tmp/log.dtruss
> $
> ```

..., - even if, if I just run `bash --login` on that OSX machine, I can see the above `echo` being printed, which means `~/.bash_profile` must be loaded?!

Of course, `dtruss` does report accessing other files:

```
$ grep 'open\|stat' /tmp/log.dtruss 
41819/0xce5a2:  stat64("/AppleInternal\0", 0x7FFF5CBC2A88, 0x0)      = -1 Err#2
41819/0xce5a2:  stat64("/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib\0", 0x7FFF5CBC23F8, 0x7FFF5CBC3330)         = 0 0
41819/0xce5a2:  open("/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
41819/0xce5a2:  stat64("/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib\0", 0x7FFF5CBC2208, 0x7FFF5CBC30A0)        = 0 0
...
41819/0xce5a2:  open("/dev/tty\0", 0x6, 0x7FFF79D33940)      = 3 0
41819/0xce5a2:  open_nocancel("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = 3 0
...
41819/0xce5a2:  stat64("~/.fastlane/bin/bash\0", 0x7FFF5CBC37E0, 0x0)        = -1 Err#2
41819/0xce5a2:  stat64("/usr/bin/bash\0", 0x7FFF5CBC37E0, 0x0)       = -1 Err#2
41819/0xce5a2:  stat64("/bin/bash\0", 0x7FFF5CBC37E0, 0x0)       = 0 0
41819/0xce5a2:  stat64("/bin/bash\0", 0x7FFF5CBC3820, 0x0)       = 0 0
...
```

..., for instance we can see that the `$HOME` directory is accessed as part of searching through `$PATH` (and in fact, that `PATH="~/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"` *is*  set in that very same `~/.bash_profile`).

My question is - how come this happens? Is there a special invocation of `dtruss` that I need to use, so it reports when files like `~/.bash_profile` are accessed? Or is there another program on OSX that I should use to achieve the same kind of file open tracing, that `strace` allows on Linux? Or is the process starting on OSX so different, that it "loads" `~/.bash_profile` for a `bash` process somehow in the background, before `bash` ever starts running as a standalone process?

Comment: When I run `sudo dtruss -f bash --login 2>&1 | tee blah` I see `open("/var/root/.bash_profile\0", 0x0, 0x272)   = -1 Err#2` in the log. That's the MacPorts version of `bash`. The vendor provided `/bin/bash` gets `dtrace: failed to execute /bin/bash: dtrace cannot control executables signed with restricted entitlements`

Comment: Do you log into Ubuntu machine with ssh also ?